# Java equivalent of php chr() function

Tags: java, php

I need to port some **PHP** code to **Java**. Some part of the code uses
 `chr()` function.
I tried using `int to (char)` in the **Java** implementation but both yield different result

```php
// PHP
chr(171) 
// Outputs: �
```

```java
// Java
System.out.println((char)171);
// Outputs:  «**
```

How can I get the same results from both functions?

Comment: Are PHP and Java using different character encodings?

Comment: how to figure that out?

Comment: Are you printing to browser, debug window or command line?

Comment: Depending on your php version, you may be able to try `mb_chr(171)`.

Comment: When looking at a codepoint table (https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) you can see for 171 (U+00AB) the char `«`. I wonder if your PHP version also tries to show that, but your font doesn't support it?

Comment: @Sal I am printing on terminal

Comment: FWIW, PHP's `chr()` function does not really know/care about encodings. It just grabs an integer variable variable and produces a binary 1-byte string with such value.